# Python Or Tools minimize sum of square differences

Tags: python, python-3.x, or-tools, cp-sat

I'm new to googles ortools, and I'm trying to use cp_model fot this problem:

I have a matrix "agents" of size *d x s* (my decision variables), a transition matrix "shifts_coverage" size *s x p* and an objective matrix "objetive" of size   *d x p*.
I want to Minimize

[image]

where "*" denotes a matrix multiplication. So I wrote

```
model.Minimize(sum(np.power([np.dot(agents, shifts_coverage) - objetive]),2))
```

agents is a `model.NewIntVar`, and "shifts_coverage" and "objetive" are fixed input matrixes.

However I get an error where it says  `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): '_SumArray' and 'int'` if I remove the np.power the error is  `is not a valid objective`.
So I'm not sure how this objetive function should be defined in order to have the expected format from ortools.
I've also seen something called `model.AddAbsEquality`, it seems its related, but I have not been able to successfuly implement it in this objetive function

Thanks!

**EDIT:**
I've tried using intermediate variables as suggested, but as I want to minimize an square difference,  I tried something like this

- Express the square diff as a multiplication of absolute values, as my matrixes are positives
  [image]
- For the term agents * shifts_coverage, I added another variable called shifted_agents as

`shifted_agents [d][p] = sum([agents[d][s] * shifts_coverage[s][p] for s in range(num_shifts)])`

Remember shifts_coverage[s][p] is just a bool and agents[d][s] is a model.NewIntVar (I think this may be the problem)

- For absolute value used the trick of intermediate variables with

```
abs_difference[d][p] = model.NewIntVar(0, 100, f'abs_difference_d{d}p{p}')
model.AddAbsEquality(abs_difference[d][p], shifted_agents[d][p] - objetive[d][p])
```

The idea after this, is implement the AddMultiplicationEquality with the abs_difference, but as this far, I get this error:

```
TypeError('NotSupported: model.GetOrMakeIndex(' + str(arg) +
TypeError: NotSupported: model.GetOrMakeIndex((((agents_d0s2)) + -objetive_d0p0))
```

**Note:** I removed the for loops, but left the indixes to understand the matrix dimensions

Answer (score 2):

Plus AddMultiplicationEquality to create intermediate variables.

That is

```
model.Minimize(a**2 + b**2)
```

This will not work directly, as the objective, as well as equations you add must be linear.

```
square_a = model.NewIntVar(0, max_a**2, 'square_a')
model.AddMultiplicationEquality(square_a, [a, a])
square_b = model.NewIntVar(0, max_b**2, 'square_b')
model.AddMultiplicationEquality(square_b, [b, b])
model.Minimize(square_a + square_b)
```

will do the trick.

Comment: Thanks Lauren for your response, could you please elavorate a little bit more how those methods are related and how should be passed? It would have to add an equality per "row"?. Sorry, I'm quite new to ortools and still trying to understand how everything is related

Comment: Thanks Laurent, I'll give it a try!

Comment: Hi, Laurent, I think I know understand how to implement the intermediate variables trick with ortools, could you please take a look on my original post **edit**? I think the error is actually in the multiplication of my decision variables with an input matrix. Thanks!

Comment: AddAbsEquality takes two variables. You need to create another temporary variable `difference == shifted_agents[d][p] - objetive[d][p]`.

Comment: I'd already tried making this temporary variable, but the error keeps been the same.
```agents_abs_difference[d][s] = model.NewIntVar(0,  max_relative_agents, f'agents_difference_d{d}s{s}')
agents_difference[d][s] == agents[d][s] - objetive[d][s]``` #Also tried making this a NewIntVar and adding the subtraction as a constrain.

```
model.AddAbsEquality(agents_abs_difference[d][s], agents_difference)```

Comment: When I print(agents_difference[d][s] it shows for example agents_d0_s0 - 50, I don't know if this may be a problem when latter passed to ```AddAbsEquality```

Comment: because this is not a variable but a linear expression.

Comment: and is there any way I can pass this linear expression into the AddAbsEquality?

Comment: or is there any other approach/formulation that may be compatible with this problem and ortools? Thanks!

Comment: I think I managed to solve it, in case it helps someone else, I changed my problem from ```min |x-a|```,  to ```min t, s.t t>= x-a and t>= a-x```, this way there is no problem with variables definition